# c# find keywords in a list and create new list from the found items

Tags: c#, list

i am learning c# and have the following problem, i can not find a solution.

the code i am trying is:

```
string theString = "aaa XXX,bbb XXX,ccc XXX,aaa XXX";          
List<string> listFromTheString= new List<string>(theString.Split(','));           
List<string> listOfFoundItems = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < (listFromTheString.Count); i++)
{
    if(listFromTheString[i].Contains("aaa"))
    {
        listOfFoundItems.Add(listFromTheString[i]);
    }   
}
```

I would like to iterate through the list and create new items in a new list if a special keyword is found. The list listOfFoundItems does not get filled with the founds.

can you please give me a hint what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Your code works fine. listOfFoundItems will contain 2 entries. What makes you think something is wrong with the code?

Comment: Whats your question?, this code run successfully and listOfFoundItems contains 2 element finally.

Comment: ok guys i am sorry (and happy). please give me a minute to check that back. -confused right now- :)

Comment: Let's do not downwote new SO user and advice how to solve his problem even question is not so great and clean as well

Comment: @sll:  The downvotes are legitimate.  The provided code does not illustrate the problem and, in fact, does exactly what is desired.

Comment: @Austin Salonen : OP was registered just Today, we should be patient for such cases, this is my point of view

Comment: First let me excuse. The question seems not well formulated and the code seems to work. shame on me. it seems my problem has to do with my environment. i was thinking that i am doing it wrong because i have not much experience with c#. I am working in vvvv. it has a builtin c# editor and compiler. I was outputting the new list to a string array so i can work with it further inside of vvvv. that seems somehow not to work out. the output was two items but one was empty when searching for aaa. when serching for bbb i am getting just one empty item back. I have to search the answer in vvvv forums.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this more succinctly with LINQ:

```
        string theString = ("aaa XXX,bbb XXX,ccc XXX,aaa XXX");

        List<string> listFromTheString = new List<string>(theString.Split(','));

        List<string> listOfFoundItems = listFromTheString.Where(s => s.Contains("aaa")).ToList();
```

The code you provided *does* work, though.

Here's an alternate, one-line version:

```
List<string> listOfFoundItems = theString.Split(',').Where(s => s.Contains("aaa")).ToList();
```

Comment: You can get rid of interim list `listFromTheString` as well doing this in single query

Comment: @sll Yeah, I left it slightly expanded so as to not blow the poster's mind too much. I'll update with a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

```
theString.Split(',').Where(p=>p.Contains("aaa")).ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to fix your algorithm, but once you do, consider grokking this expression:

```
listofFoundItems = (from s in theString.Split(',')
                    where s.Contains("aaa")
                    select s).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provide works fine.  Given that, I suspect you may be having some string comparison issues.

This code may work better for you:

```
const string given = "aaa XXX,bbb XXX,ccc XXX,aaa XXX";
var givenSplit = new List<string>(given.Split(','));
var listOfFoundItems = new List<string>();

foreach(var item in givenSplit.Where(g => g.IndexOf("aAa", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1))
{
    listOfFoundItems.Add(item); 
}

// two items are added
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string theString = ("aaa XXX,bbb XXX,ccc XXX,aaa XXX");

    List<string> listFromTheString = new List<string>(theString.Split(','));

    List<string> listOfKeywords = new List<string> { "aaa" };

    List<string> found = (from str in listFromTheString
                         where listOfKeywords.Any(keyword => str.Contains(keyword))
                         select str).ToList<string>();
```